# jekyll category multiple words output has no space

Tags: jekyll

i don't know how i can get spaces in between category words. Can someone help? thank you...

input in my .markdown file: categories: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']

input html:

```
<div class="masonry__container row">
{% assign posts=site.posts | where:"lang", page.lang %}
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="masonry__item col-lg-4 col-md-6" data-masonry-filter="{% for category in categories %}{{category}}{% endfor %}">
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

output: 
right now i get this: data-masonry-filter="tag1tag2tag3"

But i would like to have that: data-masonry-filter="tag1 tag2 tag3"

Comment: Not relevant to the problem you're asking about, but one of those `</div>` belongs below the `{% endfor %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the join filter `{{ post.categories | join: " "}}`.